# Is there any reliable data about the correlation between the size of a species and number of individuals that belong to it?

Tags: theoretical-biology, animal-models

I'm curious to know if such a collection of data exists, so I could visualize it with a graph, and see how humans compare to other spieces of similar size.

Comment: I don't think this question is meaningfully answerable, since the number of individuals that belongs to a species changes dramatically over time as its environment changes. Consider for example, the change in the population of [the passenger pigeon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passenger_pigeon) during the past 200 years.

Comment: @jakebeal, I think that any graph/data is accompained by the year(s) it was collected.

Comment: I think that you are interestd in scaling laws https://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1809090#:~:text=In%20biology%2C%20the%20observed%20scaling,the%20mass%20of%20the%20organism.

Comment: There might be something in the field of *Macroecology*, e.g. J. Brown's Princeton Monograph (??) on the topic ...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the “size of a species” and how could it possibly be different from the number of individuals that belong to it?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft help me reword it. I mean the body size of the (average) individual belonging to that species.